# Getting the largest element in an array using recursion

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I have an assignment to use recursion to obtain the largest element in any given array.  I have the following code which will work unless the largest element is the last in the array.

Not sure how to correct this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RecursionLargestInArray
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int max = -999;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the size of the array: ");
    int arraySize = scan.nextInt();
    int[] myArray = new int[arraySize];
    System.out.print("Enter the " + arraySize + " values of the array: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
        myArray[i] = scan.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
        System.out.println(myArray[i]);
    System.out.println("In the array entered, the larget value is "
                        + getLargest(myArray, max) + ".");
}

public static int getLargest(int[] myArray, int max)
{    
    int i = 0, j = 0, tempmax = 0;
    if (myArray.length == 1)
    {
        return max;
    }
    else if (max < myArray[i])
    {
        max = myArray[i];
        int[] tempArray = new int[myArray.length-1];
        for (i = 1; i < myArray.length; i++)
        {
            tempArray[j] = myArray[i];
            j++;
        }
        tempmax = getLargest(tempArray, max);
        return tempmax;
    }
    else if
    {
        int[] tempArray = new int[myArray.length-1];
        for (i = 1; i < myArray.length; i++)
        {
            tempArray[j] = myArray[i];
            j++;
        }
        tempmax = getLargest(tempArray, max);
        return tempmax;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Just a small hint. You don't need to create a new array with every step, if you pass the index which you examined last.

Comment: Are you sure that this code doesn't work *only in the case where the last element is largest*?  It doesn't even compile for me.

Comment: @Mike - I think that last `else if` should just be an `else`. I attributed that to a typo while posting.

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984734/finding-the-largest-positive-int-in-an-array-by-recursion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first condition is the problem:

```
if (myArray.length == 1)
{
    return max;
}
```

replace it with:

```
if (myArray.length == 1)
{
    return myArray[0] > max ? myArray[0] : max;
}
```

In case of an array with only one element, you return the previous maximum. If the max is that last element, it will be skipped.

Comment: Thank you.  I saw where the error was after posting but was not sure about how to correct.  Your answer is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

you never evaluate the final element - you simply return max when the size of the array is 1, so you never actually check the final element in the array.

also, a comment - rather than creating copies of the array each time, why don't you simply pass the current index into your function every time you recurse?

Answer (score 2):

When the array length is 1, `getLargest` isn't testing the (single) array element against `max`; it's just returning `max`. That's why it's always skipping the last element.

As an aside, it would be better to initialize `max` to Integer.MIN_VALUE instead of to an arbitrary value of -999.

As a further aside, once you get your code working, it will still be terribly inefficient. You might consider posting it to [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get feedback.

Comment: Thank you.  I know that it may not be the best method.  Still just learning Java so basic is all that I need at the moment for assignment completion.  But I will post as you suggest as well.

Answer (score 2):

how about divide and conquer?

```
private static int findLargest(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit) {
    if (lowerLimit == upperLimit) {
        return temp[lowerLimit];
    } else if (upperLimit - lowerLimit == 1){
        return Math.max(temp[upperLimit], temp[lowerLimit]);
    } else {
        int pivot = (upperLimit - lowerLimit + 1)/2;
        int firstHalf = findLargest(lowerLimit, lowerLimit + pivot);
        int secondHalf = findLargest(upperLimit - pivot , upperLimit);
        return Math.max(firstHalf, secondHalf);
    }
}
```

of course temp is the global array.. and to start the recursion you call it with findLargest(0,temp.length)